# SSIS Foreeach Container Not Failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a foreach container which is looking in a share directory for files to then send on to another location.  When I ran this as part of a job the package was running successfully however the files were not being sent.  The reason was because the agent account needed access to the share.

My question is how can I get the package to fail should it not have permissions to access the directory?

Thanks

Comment: By default, it should fail in such case. What's in SSISDB log (messages)?

Comment: The All Execution reports are saying its successful, but I have just tested it again and if I remove the account the file doesn't send.

Comment: Remove the account? Please elaborate. And check the details of the reports (the "All Messages" report) to see what's happening when the package is accessing the share and trying to send the file. By the way, for running SSIS job steps, it's best practice to set up security via a dedicated account + [credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190703(v=sql.110).aspx) + [proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834(v=sql.110).aspx) instead of using the SQL Agent service account and adding more and more permissions to the Agent's account.

Answer (score -1):

Surprise, surprise, surprise!  SSIS doesn't fail the Foreach File loop container if the path is inaccessible – wow... how fun.  You'll have to add a script task to check before the loop fires.